# AWS S3 Deny File Access With Mapped Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have mapped the `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.example.com/` succesfully to `cdn.example.com` and now I have problems with file policys. And want the files from this bucket to be accessible **only** on my website running at `www.example.com`, so calling `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.example.com/com/media/fl.jpg`via browser must end in the `ACCESS DENIED`page.

- `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.example.com/com/media/fl.jpg` blocks the image as intended.
- `cdn.example.com/com/media/fl.jpg` shows the image!

**How can I fix/prevent this and block files from cdn.example.com called everywhere outside èxample.com`?**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1561234567890",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1234567890",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdn.example.com/com/folder/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1234567890",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdn.example.com/com/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you enable [s3 access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) logs on the bucket. It will log the referer value, to check what is actually used as referer when you access `cdn.example.com/com/media/fl.jpg`.

Comment: Did so now. Guess that takes a little according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/server-access-logging.html... I'll wait and see. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have now logfiles in my bucket, but no idea what to read from that? Don't see a referer in http://snippi.com/s/3aggsn9

Comment: Referrer is unknown. So `cdn.example.com/com/media/fl.jpg` should be denied due to lack of referer in my view. But it is allowed in your case?

Comment: It is allowed when linked from the site (like in the <img src="...">), yes. But should be disallowed from everywhere outside the website. The img url in the browser for example must not show the file!

Comment: Do I need to improve or rewrite my question? I was hoping for some more help :)

Comment: If it works maybe need to also check for `aws::Referer` existence using [Null](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Null) check, buy adding extra condition ` {"Null":{"aws:Referer":"false"}}`. But if the image is displayed in the browser, it has already been downloaded and cashed by your browser. So subsequent calls to it will probably just load it from cache.